# G Suite 2fa disable SMS

Tags: google-workspace-for-business, g-suite-administrator

Is there any way to disable SMS 2fa for G Suite as a company-wide policy?  I can see that you can enforce "security key" only, but we want to keep the other options available too, like Google Authenticator and Google Prompt, just no SMS option.

Comment: Have you already read [Set up 2-Step Verification for your domain](https://support.google.com/a/answer/184711?hl=en)?

Comment: Yes. Enforced. But users can still use SMS as the 2nd step.

Comment: It looks to me that you should make a feature request directly to G Support.

Comment: BTW, this is why I'm asking: https://motherboard.vice.com/en_us/article/vbqax3/hackers-sim-swapping-steal-phone-numbers-instagram-bitcoin This is happening to a lot of people recently. You can't trust SMS anymore (because you can't trust the people working at the carriers).

Answer (score -1):

- go to **https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig**
- enter your password to verify it's you
- click **Remove** next to the phone number

Comment: Sorry, I meant as a company wide policy, updated question.